# What is the meaning of (true && false || true) in C#?

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

If I have this equation:

```
    var x = (true && false || true)
```

Is that equivalent to:

```
    var x = ((true && false) || true)
```

or:

```
    var x = (true && (false || true))
```

And whats the logic behind this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx see this link to give the microsoft definition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**AND wins** over OR.

So it will be

```
var x = ((true && false) || true)
```

See [Operator precedence and associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Well, I thought it is more nicely put as such :)

Answer (score 6):

In boolean logic, "not" (`!`) is evaluated before "and" (`&&`) and "and" is evaluated before "or" (`||`).  By using the double (`&&`) and the double (`||`), these operators will short circuit, which does not affect the logical outcome but it causes terms on the right hand side to not be evaluated if needed.

Thus

`var x = (true && false || true)` evaluates to `false|| true` which evaluates to `true`

and

`var x = ((true && false) || true)` evaluates to `false || true` which evaluates to `true`

and

`var x = (true && (false || true))` evaluates to `true && true` which evaluates to `true`

Comment: I think (true && false || true) evaluates to false || true as && has precedence so it is equivalent to ((true && false) || true). Anyway in the end all of it are gonna be true.

Comment: Good catch!  I messed up typing there.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's

```
var x = ((true && false) || true)
```

...as `&&` has **[precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)** according to MSDN.

You'd think that whoever wrote that particular line of code might have made their intention clear by inserting the parenthesis in the right place. Do everyone else a favour, and add them in.

Answer (score 2):

It's equivalent to

`var x = ((true && false) || true)`

The && operator has higher precedence than the || operator.

[Operator precedence MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Your statement contains a subtle logical error. Precedence does not control the order in which subexpressions are evaluated. That is, when you say A() + B() * C() it is NOT the case that B() * C() is evaluated before A() just because * is higher precedence than +. Rather, the order of evaluation is A(), then B(), then C(), then the multiplication, then the addition. **Subexpressions** are evaluated **left to right**, end of story. Precedence and associativity work out what the subexpressions are.

Comment: @Eric: Whoops -- not what I meant to say / convey in this case; thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` has higher precedence, so the second form (of the three) is correct. As to the logic, `&&` tends to be vaguely associated with multiplication, and `||` with addition (if you use zero and non-zero to represent false and true, respectively, the operators have equivalent semantics). But mostly it's just the way it's been since C, and possibly before C.

Answer (score 0):

If you use in this expression || true that mean doesn't matter about other result it always will be true

Comment: In the real code I'm using variables. I substituted static values to simplify the question.

Answer (score 0):

The above expression evaluates as `((true && false) || true)` because of the operator precedence(&& has higher precedence than ||).

Check this link for more information on Operator Precedence: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

&& has a higher precedence than ||
so the first two use cases will act exactly the same.
The braces have no meaning here, just like in:

a * b + c = (a * b) + c

You can control precedence and associativity with braces. so the third use case will check the OR condition and then the AND.